# How to add GMSMapView to a portion of a view in swift 4

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, gmsmapview

I would like to add GMSMapView to a currentView as subview however it is showing a black page here is my code

```
    let viewTest = UIView()
    viewTest.frame = CGRect.init(x: 16, y: 50, width: 300, height: 100)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

    mapView.delegate = self
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
    viewTest.addSubview(mapView)
```

If I change `viewTest.addSubview(mapView)` to`self.view = mapView` it works fine with the map showing on my wholeview.

If I change `viewTest = mapView`. I got a white screen without map showing with the following error.

> " current[11927:300222] [BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished: line 1436 Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLFatalAlert(-9802) alert
>   2018-06-23 00:56:12.499396-0400 current[11927:300222] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x604000179c80]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
>   "

Comment: For more information you can check this demo... https://github.com/mahendragp/GoogleMapDemo

Comment: Also add self.view.addSubView(viewTest).  As you havent add viewTest in self.view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `IBOutlet` of a view and set its class to `GMSMapView`.

[image]

Create the property for the same.

```
@IBOutlet weak var view_mapContainer: GMSMapView!
```

And finally you can set its properties.

```
  let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.123312, longitude: 76.123123) //set lat long of the location you want to set

  self.view_mapContainer.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: coord, zoom: 13, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

  let marker = GMSMarker()
  marker.icon = UIImage(named: "ImageToSet")

  marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation(rawValue: 1)!
  marker.position = coord
  marker.title = "any title"
  marker.snippet = "any snippet"
  marker.map = self.view_mapContainer
```